# I am working on an ASP.NET Core 5 MVC project and want to call property from model 1 to model 2, but any view must have only one model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-5.0

Let's say this is my model:

```
public class Book
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Pages { get; set; }
}
```

and this is model 2

```
public class Author
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In any view, you must have one model `@model Book`, but I want to get a property from `Author` class in `Book` view.

Note: single-value prop - not list

Answer (score 1):

You can create a ViewModel to contains `Book` and `Author`

```
public class ViewModel
    {
        
        public Book book{ get; set; }

        public Author author{ get; set; }
    }
```

Use this  model to pass data between view and controller. Then you can call  props from both `Book` and `Author` in the same View.

More details you can refer to this [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Answer (score 0):

add navigation property to Book

```
Book {

    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Pages { get; set; }

    public int AuthorID {get; set; }

    public virtual Author Author {get; set; }
}
```

Comment: But many books I know might have **multiple** authors - so which one of those will you have in your navigation property then?